# Can I disable the external graphics card without taking it off the motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card

I have an external NVidia graphics card and wanted to check if one of my softwares which I'm developing would work without a graphics card.

Instead of having to pull out the card, I wanted to know if there's a way to temporarily disable the card or make it invisible to the OS, so that the PC would run without using the card?

The card has a VGA and DVI port. The motherboard has another VGA port. Currently my monitor is connected to the graphic card VGA port because as long as the card is present, the motherboard VGA port won't work. So I'd eventually have to use the motherboard VGA port, but can't do so if the graphic card is detected by the OS. There were no options in the NVidia control panel.

Comment: What motherboard is it? What you're describing seems like a BIOS-level issue instead of an OS-level issue. Check your BIOS settings and look for a Graphics Card Priority option.

Comment: It's an Intel motherboard. Will look at the BIOS. Thanks.

Comment: For Video, the BIOS has an 'Auto' option and 'Onboard/PEG'. The latter says "Use integrated video controller unless a PCI express graphics card is installed. The PEG card will override and disable the integrated video controller". Does this mean that I have no other option other than pulling out the graphics card? Or is there another way?

Comment: What OS is it?  You can disable under linux with acpi https://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call/

Comment: Windows XP here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 11.04 - disable NVIDIA graphics card](http://superuser.com/questions/324210/ubuntu-11-04-disable-nvidia-graphics-card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step will be BIOS, there's generally two options you'll be interested in.

The first one is graphic card priority, the actual name of the option will differ from machine to machine but it'll have options like:

PCI-E (or PEG)
Onboard
PCI-E/Onboard

For this one you want to select the option that shows both... the second option will generally be called something like Multidisplay and you want to enable that.

Between those two options you have both cards powering up and BIOS prepared to display stuff on both of them.

From there you can just go into Device Manager in Windows, right click disable the card you want to 'remove'

Comment: Under Video in BIOS, there's an 'Auto' option and 'Onboard/PEG'. The latter says "Use integrated video controller unless a PCI express graphics card is installed. The PEG card will override and disable the integrated video controller". Does this mean that I have no other option other than pulling out the graphics card? Or is there another way?

Comment: doesn't sound promising unfortunately... other way might be to get a new motherboard which does support PCI-E and onboard at same time? heh... out of curiosity is it a Lenovo because I did find the same problem with machines where I used to work and in the end all we could do was swap to gfx cards with more than one output